# Changing the menu bar font

Tags: fonts, customization

So, I'm already using Ubuntu Tweak to change the font of my UI.  There's options for everything there except for the bold title in the menu bar.  It's still set to (what I assume is) Ubuntu bold, and I'd like to change it so that it's consistent with all my other fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Menu Bar font in the Appmenu (when in Unity)  is as far as I'm aware not customizable by itself as in there's no appmenu font setting, It takes on the system fonts specifically the Title bar font, when not using the appmenu it takes on the "Default font" in the Gnome Tweak Tool settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [MyUnity](http://www.uielinux.org/myunity/)  it's great to customize your Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: not sure why this was downvotedd - works for me